# How to set custom frame rate for high refresh rate devices with Android?

Tags: android, frame-rate, surface

How can i set the frame rate to stay at 60hz?

Google says to use surface:

```
surface.setFrameRate(60f, FRAME_RATE_COMPATIBILITY_FIXED_SOURCE);
```

But how do i get the surface?

Comment: posted line is for `SurfaceView` - use `getHolder().getSurface()` for obtaining `surface`. I doubt you can modify framerate for any other type of `View` (or whole app)

Comment: Did you found some solution for this?